# Injectivity of Continued Fraction from$2^\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let g: $2^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
g(x) = x_0+\cfrac{1}{x_1+\cfrac{1}{x_2+\cfrac{1}{x_3+\,\ddots}}}
$$
Then I want to prove that $g$ is injective.

If I take two different sequence from $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and take a subtraction of them and showing that subtraction is not $0$ would be a sufficient proof?

Or, is there any more clear way that I could show this subtraction is not $0$? Since this fractions could be infinite, it raises up the problem how to prove or show this not equality in a more direct way.

Comment: If $0 \not \in \mathbb N$, then the answer is positive: the infinite continued fraction provides a homeomorphism from space of sequences of natural numbers to the space of irrational real numbers.

Comment: Rationals can be represented in two ways, one ending in $a_n - 1, 1$, the other being $\ldots, a_n$.

Comment: What is $2$ here? $\{0,1\}$? $\{1,2\}$? Zeros are a bit problematic, because well, may result in division by zero. Normally $2^{\Bbb{N}}$ could be just the power set, but that doesn't make sense here. In other words, what are $x_0,x_1,\ldots$? Natural numbers, sure, but I would then denote the collection $\Bbb{Z}_{>0}^{\Bbb{N}}$ rather than  $2^{\Bbb{N}}$.

Comment: Also, I think you should have edited [the first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312926/11619) even though it was improperply voted to be a duplicate. The remedy is always to EDIT the question to make it clearer that you are interested in mapping a sequence to a continued fraction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen got it. will follow your guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $\overline{x}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is a never-ending sequence of **positive** natural numbers.

For any such sequence $\overline{x}$ let $\overline{x}'$ stand for the sequence $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ gotten by dropping out the first entry, and moving the rest up one position. Hints:

- Show that $x_0<g(\overline{x})<x_0+1$, so if $g(\overline{x})=g(\overline{y})$ then $x_0=y_0$.
- Also $g(\overline{x})=x_0+1/g(\overline{x}')$. So if $g(\overline{x})=g(\overline{y})$ then $x_0=y_0$ and $g(\overline{x}')=g(\overline{y}')$.
- Induction!

Comment: This assumes that the convergence of such continued fractions has already been explained to you. Otherwise it is dangerous to assume that $g(\overline{x})$ exists as a positive real number.